# TCP sockets never get closed

Tags: c, sockets, select, freebsd

I have a `pselect` running that is waiting on a TCP connection. That `pselect` is running in its own thread, thus I have a bunch of them running.

I have a timeout set on those `pselect` however, it seems when I run `sockstat`, I have some connections that NEVER get closed. 99% of them do. When I close the client that is making the connections altogether, I would think that after the timeout period, I'd be able to close those sockets. I have put breakpoints to check for a return value of zero, but it never happens.

In psuedo this is what I have

```
if((ret == pselect(..., timeout, NULL) <0 ){
//check errors
} else if (ret == 0)
{
//close connection for timing out
//I never land here, even though I can close the client side (thus presumably closing the connection)
}
```

What else can I do to debug if that is my problem? it's hard for me to tell exactly which socket fd's are getting left open, though I can see them in sockstat.

Answer (score 2):

Your thread is probably spinning in the (not included) `else` case because a socket which is closed from the other end is both readable and writable.  To get in the timeout case you'd want to hold the other end open for the timeout duration.

(The case you're in is `POLLHUP` in `poll()` terms)

Comment: I see...I will give this a try..I did have some other else blocks to check for the fd's in the set, but I don't think I just had a catch-all else

Comment: @Derek: You don't need a catch-all `else`, just in some other clause than you've shown you will see that a remotely closed socket is in the read set and `recv` is going to return `ECONNRESET`.

Comment: It will return zero if the peer disconnected gracefully.